# Bundled Product "Add to Cart" immediately?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, cart, frontend, addtocart

When I am on the category list of products, and I hit "Add to Cart" on simple products, I get redirected to the cart with the product added to the cart.

However, when I add a Bundled product, even if the bundle has no configurable options, I always get redirected to the product page, where I have to click on "Add to Cart" again.

Is there a way to "fix" this so if I click "Add to Cart" on a bundled product from the category list view, it gets added to the cart immediately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the "Add to Cart" button on the category list page is governed by this functionality in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract`, as shown [here](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.9.1.1/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Abstract.php#L115).  As the logic goes, if there are *any* required options in the product, "Add to Cart" is set to the product URL, not an "Add to Cart" URL.

The solution is to replace this block function with your own, that *always* adds the product to the cart.

```
// Always add product to cart.
public function getAddToCartUrl($product, $additional = array()) {
    return $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product, $additional);
}
```

More precisely, you need to create a block that extends `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List`, and in your `config.xml` you need to rewrite the `product_list` block inside the `catalog` module:

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <product_list>Foo_Bar_Block_Product_List</product_list>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </blocks>
</global>
```